# How can I manage a pool of VMs for running untrusted code in a Node.js application?

Tags: node.js, virtual-machine

I have a Node.js app that acts as an API for a RoR frontend. It accepts untrusted code (swift, currently - eventually a variety of languages), executes this code and returns the output or an error. It's for an application kind of like [this](http://swiftstub.com/).

We would like to decouple the web server and code execution so that our web server can't be brought down by unsafe or long-running code, and we aren't forced into using a specific platform for the web server (Mac OS X currently). It seems like the way to do this is to manage a pool of virtual machines (and terminate ones that stop responding - with feedback to the node app so that we can block malicious users).

I've looked into a few solutions for this, but I may be missing something and I don't want to go down the wrong path. Has anybody done something like this before?

I would prefer not to be tied to tools provided by a specific hosting provider (like AWS), and what we have currently is written in Node, as mentioned, but if different tools offer a much better solution to this problem, I am open to using them.

Comment: have you considered the architecture when you spin them on the same machine using say vagrant and then scale the layer where you have nodejs?

Comment: codepad.org does something similar. They have a few things to say about how they do it [on their about page](http://codepad.org/about), but they don’t go into excruciating detail…

Comment: What are you really asking for help with here?  Are you asking for architectural advice?  Or help implementing some specific solution?